# AngularJS ui-grid enableCellEdit NOT editing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-grid

I am trying to learn AngularJS.

The grid displays properly. It loads page properly.

- It does NOT go into edit mode.
- Double click does not go into edit mode.
- `F2` does not go into edit mode.

`ProductTitle` (the second column below) is the example I am using.

I recieve no errors in `Chrome`.  No missing `libraries`.

I have spent hours researching this (and learned so much) but 
I can't get it to go into edit mode.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

`module`:

```
app = angular.module('UIGrid_App', [
    'ngAnimate', // support for CSS-based animations
    'ngTouch', //for touch-enabled devices
    'ui.grid', //data grid for AngularJS
    'ui.grid.pagination', //data grid Pagination
    'ui.grid.resizeColumns', //data grid Resize column
    'ui.grid.moveColumns', //data grid Move column
    'ui.grid.pinning', //data grid Pin column Left/Right
    'ui.grid.selection', //data grid Select Rows
    'ui.grid.autoResize', //data grid Enabled auto column Size
    'ui.grid.exporter', //data grid Export Data
    'ui.grid.edit'
  ]);
})();
```

`controller`:

```
app.controller('ProductsCtrl', ['$scope', 'CRUDService', 'uiGridConstants',
function ($scope, CRUDService, uiGridConstants) {
$scope.gridOptions = [];

//ui-Grid Call
$scope.GetProducts = function () {
$scope.gridOptions = {
enableCellSelection: true, // jenny changed to editable
enableCellEdit: false, // jenny changed to editable - to be set below ( setting to true doesnt work)
enableCellEditOnFocus: true, // jenny changed to editable
useExternalPagination: true,
useExternalSorting: true,
enableFiltering: true,
enableSorting: true,
enableRowSelection: true,
enableSelectAll: true,
enableGridMenu: true,

columnDefs: [
{
name: "ProductID",
displayName: "Product ID",
width: '10%',
headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader
},
{
name: "ProductTitle",
title: "Product Title",
width: '40%',
enableCellEdit: true, // jenny change to editable
headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader
},
```

more columns

Comment: `enableCellEdit: false` says false - i.e. not editable. Can you create a plnkr  to reproduce the problem ?

Comment: Have you added ` ui-grid-edit` to your HTML div as attribute ? http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable

Comment: @bhantol I kept enableCellEdit: false in $scope.gridOptions = { because I did not want all columns to be editable and enableCellEdit: true in columnDefs .  Your recommendation for ui-grid-edit worked.

Comment: Can you post your HTML snippet ?

Comment: @bhantol Is there a way I can mark this as answered by you?  Thanks!

Comment: You can try accepting answer. I am assuming adding the attribute worked. I have missed that myself once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the documentation we need module, flags and attribute.

> [The ui.grid.edit feature allows inline editing of grid data. To enable, you must include the 'ui.grid.edit' module and you must include the ui-grid-edit directive on your grid element.](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable)

For individual cells to enable/disable use something like below in the column definition if you don;t want to enable all columns editable:

> `{ name: 'address.city', enableCellEdit: true, }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add grid edit on your html (ui-grid-edit ui-grid-row-edit)

```
<div id="grid-create-profile" ui-grid="$ctrl.gridOptions" ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-cellNav ui-grid-edit ui-grid-row-edit ui-grid-resize-columns  ui-grid-selection class="grid"></div>
```